# Passing struct array to function

Tags: c

I have set up these structs. I wanted to know whether option1 and option2 are equivalent and will bring about the same functionality.
changeInfo(student) will be called from another function where space for INFO * arr will be malloced.

```
typedef struct{
    int grade;
    int age;

}INFO; 

typedef struct {
    int idNum;
    INFO * arr;
}STUDENT;

void changeInfo(STUDENT * student){
   //OPTION 1
   resetInfo(student)
   // or OPTION 2
   resetInfo(student->arr);
}

//option 1
void resetInfo(STUDENT * s){
     s->arr[0].grade = 0;
     s->arr[0].age = 0;

}
//option 2
void resetInfo(INFO * info){
    info[0].grade = 0;
    info[0].age = 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried testing it yourself?

Comment: yes, they are the same

Comment: As they stand, they are approximately equivalent, and approximately equally restricted.  Each student most likely has many `INFO` records, though you don't show how you know how many there are.  If you pass a student record, you could reset multiple INFO records, if you wrote the code appropriately. If you pass an `INFO` pointer, you can use it in places where you don't have a student record but do have INFO records.  There are many opportunities for problems with null pointers, etc.  There isn't enough information about how it will be used to come up with a definitive, opinion-based answer.

Comment: For the reusability of your code, option 2 is better : you can use it to reset any info, not only student's info.